# How to quickly get a 'column' from a 'matrix'? (not necessarily numbers)

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, matrix

Fellas,

Suppose I have this list of lists:

```
l=[['-40', 'TT', '0.8', '0', '10U', '4'],
['125', 'FF', '0.8', '0', '10U', '16'],
['125', 'FF', '0.8', '0', '10U', '4' ],
['30', 'FF', '0.8', '0', '10U', '64'],
['125', 'FF', '0.3', '0', '1U', '16' ],
['125', 'FF', '0.8', '0', '1U', '4'  ],
['30', 'FF', '0.8', '0', '1U', '64' ],
['125', 'FF', '0.8', '0', '4U', '16' ],
['125', 'SS', '0.8', '0', '4U', '4'  ],
['125', 'FF', '0.8', '0', '4U', '64' ],
['125', 'FF', '0.8', '1', '10U', '4' ],
['125', 'FF', '0.8', '1', '1U', '4'  ],
['125', 'SS', '0.8', '1', '4U', '4'  ],
['125', 'FF', '0.9', '16', '10U', '64'],
['125', 'FF', '0.8', '16', '1U', '64'],
['125', 'FF', '0.8', '16', '4U', '64'],
['125', 'FF', '0.8', '2', '10U', '4' ],
['125', 'FF', '0.8', '2', '1U', '4'  ] 
]
```

As you might notice it is a matrix of size (18x6) where the elements are strings representing float only in some columns.

I can happily sort it on the 3rd column by applying

```
newL = sorted(l, key = lambda t: float(t[2]))
```

newL content will be (I suppress [,] from now on):

```
'125', 'FF', '0.3', '0', '1U', '16'
'-40', 'TT', '0.8', '0', '10U', '4'
'125', 'FF', '0.8', '0', '10U', '16'
'125', 'FF', '0.8', '0', '10U', '4'
'30', 'FF', '0.8', '0', '10U', '64'
'125', 'FF', '0.8', '0', '1U', '4'
'30', 'FF', '0.8', '0', '1U', '64'
'125', 'FF', '0.8', '0', '4U', '16'
'125', 'SS', '0.8', '0', '4U', '4'
'125', 'FF', '0.8', '0', '4U', '64'
'125', 'FF', '0.8', '1', '10U', '4'
'125', 'FF', '0.8', '1', '1U', '4'
'125', 'SS', '0.8', '1', '4U', '4'
'125', 'FF', '0.8', '16', '1U', '64'
'125', 'FF', '0.8', '16', '4U', '64'
'125', 'FF', '0.8', '2', '10U', '4'
'125', 'FF', '0.8', '2', '1U', '4'
'125', 'FF', '0.9', '16', '10U', '64'
```

In Matlab notation I would access this 3rd column as newL(:,3). That would give me a (column) vector containing

```
'0.3'
'0.8'
'0.8'
'0.8'
'0.8'
etc.
```

In python I can imagine extracting this vector by building it with an iteration to extract the 3rd element from any list:

```
col = []
for line in newL:
    col.append(line[2])
```

That yields :

> ['0.3', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.9']

But... is there a more pythonic way to get this third column from newL?

It's OK for me to change of data structure (maybe a list of lists is not the best way to handle this) if you have any brilliant idea about.

Comment: `col = [line[2] for line in newL]`

Comment: WIllem's answer is great. `itemgetter` is probably the best way to do this in plain Python, but if your list of lists is large it's probably a good idea to use Numpy. BTW, if you want to transpose a list of lists in plain Python, you can use `zip(*l)`. In Numpy, you can get the transpose of an array via its `.T` attribute. This operation is really fast, since it doesn't actually move anything, it just changes the way that the underlying data is accessed.

Comment: @PM 2Ring It's interesting to suggest the T (method?) for array. The python doc says numpy allows 'Efficient arrays of numeric values', but when I read the doc, it allows non-numeric items like chars. However, it does not allow strings so it would not fit my case I guess?

Comment: Numpy is primarily for processing numerical data, but it can certainly handle strings. However, it is a rather large library, and it does take some time to learn all it's features, although it's possible to pick up the essentials fairly quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can for instance use a `map(..)` over the `itemgetter` of the `operator` package:

```
from operator import itemgetter

result = map(itemgetter(2), newL)
```

Or without builtins, you can use *list comprehension*:

```
result = [row[2] for row in newL]
```

both yield:

```
>>> map(itemgetter(2), newL)
['0.3', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.9']
>>> [row[2] for row in newL]
['0.3', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.9']
```

In [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7), `map` constructs a list, in [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) however, a `map` is a lazy iterable. In order to materialize the list, you then need to surround it with `list(..)`.

You can also use *numpy* and perform advanced indexing:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(newL)
result = a[:,2]
```

the result is then a numpy array:

```
>>> a[:,2]
array(['0.3', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8',
       '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.8', '0.9'],
      dtype='<U3')
```

but this will only work on rectangular lists of lists.